# Smooth Grid Based Movement withJavascript

Tags: javascript, function, game-development, keyboard-events

I am creating a grid-based movement RPG game that transitions from a 16-pixel tile to the next 16-pixel tile. The problem is that it is not smooth while switching keys and sometimes randomly slows down and speeds up if you hold a key long enough

So here is what I did. I first created Booleans for each direction and on key down the direction the key was pressed in would turn true and all other direction booleans would turn false. on keyup the boolean that was released would turn false. I then created a function that would handle the variable called variableHandler.
it would just check which direction you had to move in and there would be a variable checking how much distance to the next space using x % 16 and another variable for y % 16.  If one variable was false you couldn't take any keyboard input other than then keyup until the variables were true again. Based on the direction that you started moving in you would move the rest of the way in the same direction (there was another variable which decided the direction you would have to keep moving in which turns false after your x or y is divisible by 16). The function loop happened every 20 milliseconds. there were no loops or while loops involved. There was a loop that would draw the hero to the proper spot every 10 milliseconds.
there were no console errors. in general, the movement if you switched keys or kept moving in the same direction switched your speed and/or caused delay.

Comment: Please include the code that demonstrates the problem.